# Approximating $\sum\limits_{r\subset S}|r|!\prod\limits_{x\in r}x$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, approximation

There is a set $S=\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_N\}.$

I'm trying to approximate this:
$$p(S)=\sum_{r\subset S}|r|!\prod_{x\in r}x$$

I know that:

$$\sum_{r\subset S}\prod_{x\in r}x=\prod_{x\in S}(1+x)$$

I was wondering if there is a way to approximate $p(S)$ with something.

---

**An idea:**
Change $x$ in $\prod\limits_{x\in S}(1+x)$ to $a(x)x$ so that:

$$\prod_{x\in S}(1+a(x)x)\sim\sum_{r\subset S}|r|!\prod_{x\in r}x$$

---

**Stirling's approximation**

There is: $$n! \sim (2\pi n)^\frac{1}{2}(\frac{n}{e})^n$$
which for my problem $n^n$ is troubling and I can't fiure out a way for $\prod_{x\in S}(1+a(x)x)$ to make $n^n$. It could also go up to a power of e: 
$$n! \sim e^{log(2\pi)/2-n+nlog(n)}$$
But again, can't figure out to handle $nlog(n)$.

---

Comment: Are all the $x_i$s (positive) integers?

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 yes

Comment: Perhaps this lower bound may be of some use to you  $p(S)\geq 1+\sum_{x\in S}x+\sum_{r\subset S,|r|>1}2^{|r|}\prod_{x\in r} x\geq 1+\sum_{x\in S}{x}+\sum_{r\subset S,|r|>1}\sum_{n\in 2^r}\prod_{x\in n}x=1+\sum_{x\in S}{x}+\sum_{r\subset S,|r|>1}\sum_{n\subset r}\prod_{x\in n}x=1+\sum_{x\in S}{x}+\sum_{r\subset S,|r|>1}\prod_{x\in r}(1+x)\geq 1+\sum_{x\in S}x+\sum_{r\subset S}\prod_{x\in r}(1+x)-1-\sum_{x\in S}(1+x)=\sum_{r\subset S}\prod_{x\in r}(1+x)-|S|=\sum_{t\subset S+1}\prod_{y\in t}y-|S|=\prod_{y\in S+1}(1+y)-|S|=\prod_{x\in S}(2+x)-|S|$

Comment: In your last comment, when you have for the term where $r=\emptyset$, you have $(-1)!$, could you explain what that is ? Also from since it is combinatorics, I would say that it is just that you should add a condition that $|r|\geq 1$ right ?

Comment: @P.Quinton yup, your right. thanks.

Comment: @P.Quinton I tested your answer with a little set and was working on it to see whats wrong. Was it hopeless?

Comment: @Anais I'm pretty sure I screwed something, if I can fix it I will undelete it. You didn't get the right result right ?

Comment: @P.Quinton There was a huge gap.

Comment: This may be of use : suppose you change the notations and use lists instead of sets in order to allow for repetition of elements. Then for some $y\in S$, we can see that $p(S)=p(S-y)+y (p(S-y+1)-p(S-y))$ where $S-y$ is the list $S$ without one of the occurrence of $y$ and $S-y+1$ is the list $S$ without one of the occurrence of $y$ and with an added occurrence of $1$. This gives you a recurrence relation with a decreasing size of $S$ or elements of $S$ being replaced by $1$.

Comment: @P.Quinton thanks but I need $p(s)$ or an approximation of it as part of an equation to use in an optimization problem and I'm desperate.

Answer (score 1):

We can find an easy upper bound for $p(S)$ in the function $\prod_{x\in S}(1+x^2)$, as $$\prod_{x\in S}(1+x^2)=\sum_{r\subset S}\prod_{x\in r}x^2=\sum_{r\subset S}\bigg(\prod_{x\in r}x\bigg)^2=\sum_{r\subset S}\bigg(\prod_{x\in r}x\bigg)\prod_{x\in r}x\geq\sum_{r\subset S}|r|!\prod_{x\in r}x=p(S)$$

(the inequality holding as all $x$'s are positive integers)
For a lower bound, you could use the product $\prod_{x\in S}(1+x)$, as you have mentioned.

Correcting what I wrote in a comment, you could also use $\prod_{x\in S}(2+x)-R(S)$ where $R(S)$ is a remainder term.

$$p(S)=\sum_{r\subset S}|r|!\prod_{x\in r}x=\\\sum_{r\subset S,|r|=0}0!\prod_{x\in r}x+\sum_{r\subset S,|r|=1}1!\prod_{x\in r}x+\sum_{r\subset S,|r|=2}2!\prod_{x\in r}x+\sum_{r\subset S,|r|=3}3!\prod_{x\in r}x+\sum_{r\subset S,|r|>3}|r|!\prod_{x\in r}x=\\ 1+\sum_{x\in S}x+2\sum_{x,y\in S\\x\neq y}xy+6\sum_{x,y,z\in S\\x\neq y\neq z}xyz+\sum_{r\subset S,|r|>3}|r|!\prod_{x\in r}x\geq\\ 1+\sum_{x\in S}x+2\sum_{x,y\in S\\x\neq y}xy+6\sum_{x,y,z\in S\\x\neq y\neq z}xyz+\sum_{r\subset S,|r|>3}2^{|r|}\prod_{x\in r}x\geq\\ 1+\sum_{x\in S}x+2\sum_{x,y\in S\\x\neq y}xy+6\sum_{x,y,z\in S\\x\neq y\neq z}xyz+\sum_{r\subset S\\|r|>3}\sum_{n\in 2^{|r|}}\prod_{x\in n}x=\\1+\sum_{x\in S}x+2\sum_{x,y\in S\\x\neq y}xy+6\sum_{x,y,z\in S\\x\neq y\neq z}xyz+\sum_{r\subset S\\|r|>3}\sum_{n\subset r}\prod_{x\in n}x=\\ 1+\sum_{x\in S}x+2\sum_{x,y\in S\\x\neq y}xy+6\sum_{x,y,z\in S\\x\neq y\neq z}xyz+\sum_{r\subset S\\|r|>3}\prod_{x\in r}(1+x)=\\\bigg(1+\sum_{x\in S}x+2\sum_{x,y\in S\\x\neq y}xy+6\sum_{x,y,z\in S\\x\neq y\neq z}xyz\bigg)+\sum_{r\subset S}\prod_{x\in r}(1+x)-\bigg(1+\sum_{x\in S}(1+x)+\sum_{x,y\in S\\ x\neq y}(1+x)(1+y)+\sum_{x,y,z\in S\\x\neq y\neq z}(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)\bigg)=\\\sum_{r\subset S}\prod_{x\in r}(1+x)-|S|-\binom{|S|}{2}-\binom{|S|}{3}-\frac{|S|(|S|-1)}{2}\sum_{x\in S}x-(|S|-3)\sum_{x,y\in S\\x\neq y}xy+\\5\sum_{x,y,z\in S\\x\neq y\neq z}xyz=\\\sum_{r\subset S}\prod_{x\in r}(1+x)-R(S)=\sum_{t\subset S+1}\prod_{y\in t}y-R(S)=\prod_{y\in S+1}(1+y)-R(S)=\\\prod_{x\in S}(2+x)-R(S)$$

(I have used expressions like $S+1$ above to denote the set consisting of elements of $S$ each incremented by $1$)

The upper bound represents setting $a(x)=x$ and the lower bound, setting $a(x)=1+\frac{1}{x}$, both, of course, diverge from $p(S)$ vastly for large sizes of $S$.

I can see no way of finding a function $a(x)$ that would satisfy the constraints in your question unless some additional restrictions on $S$ were added.

(please edit or comment for any corrections)